# How to make a function executino wait in android

Tags: android, geolocation

I am new to android programming. So please forgive me if it is a stupid question.

In my app,I am trying to develop a feature that if the location services would be turned off in a phone, then the app would prompt the user to turn it on by taking them to the location settings page on click of a button. The problem is that after turning on the location settings the phone is taking some time to give the location coordinates due to which the fragment that is suppose to show the coordinates is remaining empty for the same amount of time and is creating a confusion.

What I want to know is, if there is any way that I can schedule the execution of the function which is fetching the location coordinates after being sure that there is some coordinates to fetch.

I am using "getLastKnowLocation()". The code for fetching the location is below:-

```
public String getLocation()
    {
        // Get the location manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    android.location.Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    Double lat,lon;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        lat = location.getLatitude ();
        lon = location.getLongitude ();

    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){

    }
}
```

Comment: simply add a Activity circle indicating the location is being fetched. (see http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html)

Comment: were you able to solve your problem or do you need some additional info?

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable `locationLoaded`. In your following lines of code:

```
try {
    lat = location.getLatitude ();
    lon = location.getLongitude ();
    //set the value of variable to true once you get location
    locationLoaded=true;
}
catch (NullPointerException e){

}
```

Then create a new recursive method, which will keep checking for location, until it is not loaded, like this:

```
private void keepCheckingLocation(){
    if(locationLoaded){
        //location is loaded
        return;
    }
    else{
        //location is not loaded yet
        try {
            //wait for two seconds
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //call the method again to check the location
        keepCheckingLocation();
    }
}
```

Once you have called this method, it won't let the next line of code execute until the `locationLoaded` is not true and `locationLoaded` will only be true, once the location is loaded. So you can use this method whenever you want to wait for the location to get loaded.

Note: Set `locationLoaded=false;` if you have to check for locations again. It will make code more efficient.

Comment: Its a good idea. but unfortunately was not of much use as my application is getting crash after applying this logic. I am thinking it might be because I am blocking the UI thread by applying it. Thanks anyway @DroidDev

Comment: @zstart I used this method from `doInBackground` method of my `AcyncTask` class. You might also want to check the availability of your variable `locationLoaded`.